# hook_form_alter, add hidden elements such as an array

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do you attach hidden elements, or values such an array to forms via hook_form_alter ?

I can access different parts of the form, but get error when trying to add a key or value.

Comment: How do you add the key or value? What error do you get? Show some code.

Comment: It could be a good idea to tag the question with the drupal version you're using.

Comment: @KristerAndersson The Forms API and `hook_form_alter` has not changed in that respect since Drupal 6 and as far as I can tell will not change in Drupal 8 either.

Comment: @Oswald - Perhaps, that's so, but still I think it's always a good idea to include the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function sample_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FORM-ID') {
    $form['sample_module_hidden_field'] = array(
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => 'your-value',
    );
    $form['#submit'][] = 'sample_module_form_submit';
  }
}

function sample_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
   $values = $form_state['values'];

   // store the value from the hidden field
   if(!empty($values['sample_module_hidden_field'])){
      variable_set('sample_module_hidden_field', $values['sample_module_hidden_field']);
   }
}
```

You should change the `FORM-ID` to the id of the form you would like to alter. Also, of course you should alter the name and value of the field.

This is also a must read: [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)